# [__NSArrayM intValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, json, magicalrecord

I'm using MagicalRecord to pull a json file from my server. All my Objects load fine except for an equipment object. Here's the log of the JSON file

```
    "Equipment":[
  {
    "equipmentID":1,
    "equipmentName":"Barbell",
    "equipmentDescription":"Barbell"
  }
]
```

My Equipment class is a pretty basic setup

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * equipmentID;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * equipmentName;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * equipmentDescription;
```

In the data model, I have equipmentID as Integer 16. If I change it to Integer 64 then I get this error.

```
[__NSArrayM longLongValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

I don't understand what's the issue, the format is consistent with other objects in the same JSON file. The equipmentID is obviously an intValue and the Equipment class is setup as a NSNumber with equipmentID as an integer.

Any help? Is there a bug with Magical Record?

Comment: This means your Data is `NSMutableArray` rather than `NSNumber`. Check your data for the same..

Comment: Hi. Can you please put the code which you have tried to parse the json string... So we can easily identify what is the actual problem.

Comment: @iphonic But this line shows it's a NSNumber, how come it detected it as NSMutableArray?
"equipmentID":1

Answer (score 1):

You need to write like,

```
self.equipmentID = [NSNumber numberWithInt:[[[[myDic objectForKey:@"Equipment"] objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"equipmentID"] intValue]]; // Or floatValue or whatever you need.
self.equipmentName = [[[myDic objectForKey:@"Equipment"] objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"equipmentName"]; 
self.equipmentDescription = [[[myDic objectForKey:@"Equipment"] objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"equipmentDescription"];
```

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out my json is an array format (should've known from the brackets). I used MR_importFromObject instead of MR_importFromArray. Very stupid of me.